# Why would someone NOT omit the closing php tag?

Tags: php

I understand that you can omit PHP closing tags for files that are pure PHP, and that omitting the closing tag is considered good practice to avoid injecting extraneous whitespace in the output.  The opinions/standards I have looked at thus far have made it clear that we should omit closing tags on pure PHP files, but it is much less clear if we should put the closing tags when files mix HTML and PHP.  Some state outright that we need the closing tags in files mixing HTML and PHP without any evidence as to why, and others leave it ambiguous by only addressing the case of pure PHP files.

Is there some dangerous side effect to be aware of if a code base omits the PHP closing tag from all files, even if they contain HTML?

Comment: Well, usually in mixed files in my experience most of the PHP is throughout or at the very beginning of the file, not at the end. In these cases, the closing tag is required because you have to output HTML/Javascript after the PHP, but if it's at the end, it doesn't matter as much thus it's better to leave it out.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: I gotta point out that php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php is exactly the case of the docs being unclear on this question.  It answers the why you would not include the ?> tag in pure php files, but implies (by omission) that you want them when you mix php and html.  It would be better if it clearly stated you need them in the following cases, or you never need them.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there some dangerous side effect to be aware of if a code base omits the PHP closing tag from all files, even if they contain HTML?

No.

You need `?>` to switch to output mode if you want to write raw HTML.

You never need `?>` at the end of the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title: the reason is because they don't know any better. They think of `<?php` and `?>` as matching brackets, like `{` and `}`, and just make sure they're balanced out of habit.

There's no technical reason why it would ever be necessary.